# Put label on the left side of the right spine

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Given this short example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter([1,1.2,3], [5,4,3])
ax.set_xlim(0, 7)
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
axx = ax.twinx()
axx.tick_params(direction='in')
axx.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
axx.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
```

[image: plot of the given code example]

Is it possible to place the labels of the twin axis on the left side of the spline?
It is possible for the ticks but there seems to be no option to control the labels.

One can use `pad=-x` on `tick_params`, however the correct value depends on many other variables - or is there any method to control it in such a way that it works with whatever dpi, fontsize or length of label is used?

To avoid the XY problem: I have created a parallel coordinate plot using multiple adjacent subplots. The last subplot in the row has to provide two axes, as the right side of the plot is the last variable. In this plot, all axes have the labels on the left side and it looks a bit odd that the last one has it on the right.
A partial solution is to add an empty plot as the last one, which simply provides the axis.
However, in that solution the last subplot takes up space in the figure. That could be fixed using a gridspec, but it gets even more complicated to calculate the sizes correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the alignment of the labels to the right, and set the same padding as it would have normally (but negative)

```
axx.tick_params(direction='in', pad=-(plt.rcParams['ytick.major.size']+plt.rcParams['ytick.major.pad']))
plt.setp(axx.get_yticklabels(), ha='right')
```

[image]

Comment: that works like a charm! I tested also with different label lengths, and they all render correctly!